# Strassen's Algorithm proof

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I have been reading about the Strassen Algorithm for matrix multiplication.

As mentioned in Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen , the algorithm is not intuitive. However I am curious to know if there exists any rigorous mathematical proof of the algorithm and what actually went into the design of the algorithm.

I tried searching on Google and stackoverflow, but all links are only on comparing Strassen's approach to standard matrix multiplication approach or they elaborate on the procedure presented by the algorithm.

Note: The same question has been asked on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229454/strassens-algorithm-proof , but without any definite answers

Comment: Check out [this question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17040/bigger-picture-behind-the-choice-of-matrices-in-the-strassen-algorithm) on CSTheory.

Answer (score 6):

The main idea of the algorithm is to find a way to multiply two $n\times n$ matrices with less than $n^3$ "essential" multiplications (multiplications of two elements of the matrices). This forms part of a larger theory, algebraic complexity theory. Here are a few highlights:

1. Every algorithm for multiplying two matrices can be formulated (at a small loss) as a *bilinear algorithm*: you form some linear combinations $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ of entries of the first matrix, some linear combinations $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k$ of entries of the second matrix, compute $\gamma_i = \alpha_i \beta_i$, and then every entry of the product matrix is a linear combination of the $\gamma_i$.
2. This can be formulated as computing the *tensor rank* of the matrix multiplication tensor $\langle n,n,n \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n x_{ij} y_{jk} z_{ik}$. The tensor rank is similar to the more familiar matrix rank, and corresponds to the number of "essential" multiplications ($k$ in the preceding example).
3. Any non-trivial bound on $\langle n,n,n \rangle$ for *any* $n$ translates to a non-trivial matrix multiplication algorithm for *all* $n$, via the same recursive approach as Strassen's algorithm (this approach is also known as *tensorization*). There are several extensions, culminating in Schönhage's *asymptotic sum inequality*.
4. The asymptotic sum inequality can handle identities involving disjoint sums of matrix tensors (in plain English, ways of multiplying several matrices at once using fewer "essential" multiplications than the trivial algorithm uses), and can even handle "approximate" identities (*border rank*). Strassen came up with another method (the *laser method*) that can handle non-disjoint sums, and this led to the Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm and its descendants, which is where things stand today.

Comment: You say that Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm can handle non-disjoint sums. In their algorithm they speak about products of disjoint matrix products. Are the $n^{2.376}$ multiplications independants ? In other words, can these $n^{2.376}$ multiplications be computed at the same time, as the Strassen one ? Thank you

Comment: No, the Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm only works for multiplying two square matrices. Its design uses as a component the asymptotic sum inequality, which handles non-disjoint sums occurring during the design phase. The scalar multiplications generated by the algorithm can all be computed in parallel, and this is true for all matrix multiplication algorithms. That's a consequence of Strassen's normal form theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why are you talking about scalar multiplications ? This is not bilinear multiplications ?

Comment: They're multiplication of two linear combinations of matrix entries, so in the end you're multiplying two scalar quantities. You can call this operation whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks. Can the Strassen's normal form theorem be applied for any matrix product algorithm ? I don't know this theorem.

Comment: It can be applied to any algorithm computing a bilinear function of its inputs, and in particular to any matrix multiplication algorithm (in a slightly sharper form).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25449/discussion-between-user7060-and-yuval-filmus).

Comment: Thank you. I've found a lemma (here http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~slovett/teaching/SP15-CSE190/matrix-mult.pdf) but I've not found the theorem you cite.

Comment: The sharper form, which is what the lecture notes already states, ensures that each scalar product involves a linear combination of entries of one matrix multiplied by a linear combination of entries of the other matrix. The more general theorem only guarantees linear combinations of entries from both matrices, possibly mixed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you give me the reference of the original publication of the Strassen's normal form theorem ?

Comment: I believe it's referenced in my own lecture notes.

Comment: I've looked at your lecture notes, it is not referenced.

Comment: It should be referenced in the book Algebraic Complexity Theory.